# Error video-stream socket.io + socket.io-stream (Maximum call stack size exceeded)

Tags: node.js, socket.io, video-streaming, webrtc

I'm trying to create a webcam video-stream trough my node.js server with the help of socket.io and socket.io-stream.

I want to capture the video in /camera, open a stream trough socket.io (with the help of socket.io-stream) with the video, and receive it on the index url.

When I connect to the server trough /camera, and thus initiate the stream, the server crashes with the error "RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded".

The error seems to coming from "/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/has-binary/index.js:48:23".

In the examples, I left out most of the arbitrary code, as the server/connection is working fine for transferring data-snippits.

Here is my current setup:

**Server:**

```js
io.on('connection', function(socket) {

  ioStream(socket).on('videoStream', function(stream, data) {
    socket.broadcast.emit('videoStream', stream);
  });
  
});
```

**Camera**

```js
window.glob_socket = io();

var video = document.getElementById('camera');

navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia;

if (navigator.getUserMedia) {
  navigator.getUserMedia({
    audio: false,
    video: {
      width: 320,
      height: 240
    }
  }, function(videoStream) {
    // Local preview
    video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(videoStream);
    video.onloadedmetadata = function(e) {
      video.play();
    };

    // Stream
    var stream = ss.createStream();
    ss(glob_socket).emit('videoStream', stream, videoStream);
    fs.createReadStream(videoStream).pipe(stream);

  }, function(err) {
    console.log("The following error occurred: " + err.name);
  });
} else {
  console.log("getUserMedia not supported");
}
```

**Index**

```js
var video = document.getElementById('camera');

ss(glob_socket).on('videoStream', function(stream) {
  video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);

  video.onloadedmetadata = function(e) {
    video.play();
  };
});
```

I'm unable to test the code on the server/index as the server crashes when the camera initiates the stream.

Anyone has an idea what's wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't do that. [socket.io-stream](https://www.npmjs.com/package/socket.io-stream) library only deals with static files, but not with live video streams.

To share video stream you should use WebRTC. There are a couple of libraries that may help you get started:

- https://simplewebrtc.com/
- http://peerjs.com/

Worth noting that WebRTC won't transfer video through your server (in most cases). It does more - it transfers video stream from one peer to another directly, which is good for your server's bandwidth. But there might be problems when peers are behind [symmetric NAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation#Symmetric_NAT). In this case video stream should be transfered through a TURN server.

More information about WebRTC you can find [here](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webrtc/infrastructure/).

Comment: Thanks! Thought it was a little strange there was no video-stream demo.

Comment: @IbeVanmeenen if you dont mind i would ask, How did you solved it  Please share your experience with that i am having almost exact same  Issue?

Comment: @ASahra, unfortunately, I didn't go further yet with this project, so I have no solution. But I would indeed go for a WebRTC connection (maybe http://socket.io/blog/socket-io-p2p/ would work).

Comment: How much is this possible? If i want grab the getusermedia output wich is a blob object am i right? and convert it to binary then send it to server with socket and then on the server side i get the binary data then create a blob out of it and the result should be streamed? Correct me if i am wrong i am new to streaming and so.